# Core Bluetooth will not restore when coming back to view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I'm working on a bluetooth heart rate monitor and I followed the code from https://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor

I now have the app running great. Within this same app I have several other view controllers that do some other things like a login page and a simple "About Us" page. The issue I have is that when coming back to the view controller, containing the actual heart rate monitor, the monitor sits at 0 and will not update values.

I have the will restore code and delegates in place:

```
-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central willRestoreState:(NSDictionary *)state {

  NSLog(@"willRestoreState called");
    self.polarH7HRMPeripheral = [state[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey] firstItem];
    self.polarH7HRMPeripheral.delegate = self;  
  }
```

central manager is declared like so:

```
 CBCentralManager *centralManager =[[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:@{ CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:@"myCentralManagerIdentifier" }];
```

When coming back to the view controller, I noticed that `willRestoreState` is not being called.

I'm lost as to where to look next. Can anyone help out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not hold your Bluetooth object in a view controller. Hold it in another class that doesn't get deallocated

Answer (score 1):

If the object of `CBCentralManager` gets deallocated then this methods will not work as this are the delegate methods of `CBCentralManager`.

To make it work you have to reinitialize the object of `CBCentralManager`, so that you will get the heart rate.

Like this

```
self.hrCBManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
```